# Do lower Riemann sums form a connected set?

Tags: real-analysis, connectedness, riemann-sum

Let $f:[a, b] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a bounded function. The usual way of defining the Riemann integral is to take lower sums and upper sums of partitions of $[a, b]$ and going from there.

However, I stumbled upon the following question: The lower sums form a bounded set, since it is bounded from above by any upper sum and bounded from below by $C(b-a)$, where $C$ is a lower bound for $f$ on $[a, b]$. Is this set connected? In other words, given any real number $c$ between the bounds of the lower sum, can you take a partition $P$ such that the lower sum of $f$ with respect to $P$ is $c$?

My intuition tells me that this would hold for a continuous function, but I couldn't even prove it for the identity function on $[0, 1]$. Is my intuition correct? If it is, can we relax any conditions on $f$? I would really like to work on this myself, so any hints would be appreciated.

Comment: It's certainly true for continuous $f$: By the intermediate value theorem, lower sums "vary continuously with the endpoints" (endpoints are moved, or new subdivisions are appended near the end of an existing subinterval). Mod details, you should be able to get to the general case using Riemann's criterion for integrability ($f$ is continuous almost everywhere), but I haven't tried to write out the details....

Comment: If the second is at $x=c$, then the area of the first rectangle is $0$ and the area of the second rectangle is $c\cdot (1-c)$. But the parabola $x(1-x)$ doesn't take values greater than $0.25$, so not every real number between $0$ and $1$ can be obtained with two intervals. If we take three intervals, we can get up to $1/3$, so I assume that by trial and error we can find the number of points we need to be able to cover the whole $[0,1]$. I have no idea how to generalise this to an arbitrary, continuous function, though.